# Multiple tag groups for CodeDeploy in Cloudformation in YAML

Tags: amazon-web-services, yaml, aws-cloudformation, aws-code-deploy

I'm having a hard time trying to figure out how to add multiple tag groups for CodeDeploy in Cloudformation via YAML.

[Here is a example in JSON for Mutiple tag groups with single tag for ec2TagFilters](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codedeploy/latest/userguide/instances-tagging.html#instances-tagging-example-3).  I know how to create multiple tags in the same tag group, but I can't seem to figure out how to create multiple tag groups using YAML.

Can someone help?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you're having problems converting between JSON and YAML, you should use tools like [this website](https://www.json2yaml.com/) to help you. I plugged in the documentation you reference, and this is what I got:

```
ec2TagSetList:
- - Key: KEY_AND_VALUE
    Type: Name
    Value: AppVersion-ABC
- - Key: KEY_AND_VALUE
    Type: Region
    Value: North
- - Key: KEY_AND_VALUE
    Type: Type
    Value: t2.medium
```

Comment: does not work:  UPDATE_FAILED AWS::CodeDeploy::DeploymentGroup WebGroup Encountered unsupported property ec2TagSetList

Answer (score 1):

The AWS Documentation is really frustrating here...

First, case is inconsistent across documentation:
"ec2TagSetList" they frequently start with lowercase in documentation (which is incorrect)

"Ec2TagSetList" is what you want to use

That said, there is even more inconsistency where the documentation above is just wrong with the syntax...

This is the correct syntax for a single tag group:

```
  ResourceNameHere:
    Type: AWS::CodeDeploy::DeploymentGroup
    Properties: 
      ...
      Ec2TagSet:
        Ec2TagSetList:
          - Ec2TagGroup:
              - Type: KEY_AND_VALUE
                Key: "Tag1Key"
                Value: "Tag1Value"
              - Type: KEY_AND_VALUE
                Key: "Tag2Key"
                Value: "Tag2Value"
      ...
```

If you want to configure multiple tag groups just add another Ec2TagGroup:

```
  ResourceNameHere:
    Type: AWS::CodeDeploy::DeploymentGroup
    Properties: 
      ...
      Ec2TagSet:
        Ec2TagSetList:
          - Ec2TagGroup:
            - Type: KEY_AND_VALUE
              Key: "Tag1Key"
              Value: "Tag1Value"
            - Type: KEY_AND_VALUE
              Key: "Tag2Key"
              Value: "Tag2Value"
          - Ec2TagGroup:
            - Type: KEY_AND_VALUE
              Key: "Tag3Key"
              Value: "Tag3Value"
            - Type: KEY_AND_VALUE
              Key: "Tag4Key"
              Value: "Tag4Value"
      ...
```